# Polymer's iron-list won't show

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm playing with Google's Polymer library and I have trouble with iron-list component. It simply is not rendered and no error is thrown.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="odTimeTracker - UI test with Polymer">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
    <title>odTimeTracker</title>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-styles/classes/typography.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-image/iron-image.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-scroll-header-panel/paper-scroll-header-panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body unresolved>
    <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
        <iron-ajax auto url="activities-json.php" handle-as="json"
                   last-response="{{data}}"></iron-ajax>
        <paper-scroll-header-panel class="fit" condenses keep-condensed-header>
            <paper-toolbar class="tall">
                <paper-icon-button icon="arrow-back"></paper-icon-button>
                <div class="flex"></div>
                <paper-icon-button icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
                <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert"></paper-icon-button>
                <div class="bottom title">odTimeTracker</div>
            </paper-toolbar>
            <iron-list items="[[data.items]]" as="item">
                <template>
                    <div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <b><code>[[item.ActivityId]]</code></b>
                            <div class="pad">
                                <div class="primary">[[item.Name]]</div>
                                <div class="secondary">[[item.Started]] &ndash; [[item.Stopped]]</div>
                                <div class="secondary dim">[[item.Description]]</div>
                            </div>
                            <iron-icon icon$="[[iconForItem(item)]]"></iron-icon>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </iron-list>
        </paper-scroll-header-panel>
    </template>
    <script>
document.querySelector('template[is=dom-bind]').iconForItem = function(item) {
    return item ? (item.Stopped == '' ? 'star-border' : 'star') : '';
};

document.addEventListener('paper-header-transform', function(event) {
    var title = this.querySelector('.title');
    var detail = event.detail;
    var deltaHeight = detail.height - detail.condensedHeight;
    var scale = Math.max(0.6, (deltaHeight - detail.y) / (deltaHeight / 0.4)  + 0.6);

    Polymer.Base.transform('scale(' + scale + ') translateZ(0)', title);
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem is not in consumed JSON (because it's working in other test I written) and I can not figure what the problem is. The code above results just into blank page with header rendered.

Comment: anything pops up on your debug console?

Comment: nothing (as I wrote).

Comment: And the JSON self (activities-json.php) is loaded (at least is displayed in network console)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to import `iron-list`, throw this in:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-list/iron-list.html">
```

Comment: No problem! Happens to me all the time, especially in between coffees.

Comment: I experienced the exact same problem and found myself here. Day three figuring out Polymer so newby error.  Interesting that no errors are reported anywhere. Just an empty list.  I'm working out of the polymer start kit generated code to start with (for learning).  No build step I tried complained about the missing, but necessary, link.

Comment: FWIW, polymer-cli now has a 'lint' command that will report a missing import: `warning [undefined-elements] - The element iron-list is not defined`